# Percent height and top distance render differently when delivered through express and webpack

Tags: html, css, reactjs, webpack, semantic-ui

I have a React component which is not rendering properly when I deliver it to client through webpack. It however renders properly, when delivered via express through jade. Attached screenshot showcases the problem - on the left: express through jade and on the right: through webpack.

Top distance (red line) and Height of container (blue line) render differently when delivered via express through jade (left screen) and webpack (right screen):

[image]

Not sure if it is any help, but below is the HTML and snippets of classes which are relevant. Also, adding the webpack config file.

HTML:

```
<div id="main" class="ui container my-grid-container">
 <div data-reactroot="" class="ui stackable grid">
  <div class="centered row">
   <div class="eight wide column">
    <div class="my-container">
    <!-- react-text: 5 --><!-- /react-text -->
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="centered row">
   <div class="eight wide column">
    <div class="my-container2">
     <div class="my-container2-item">
      <div class="my-container2-item-content"> 
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.my-grid-container {
  position: relative;
  top: 15%;
}

.my-container {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  width: auto;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 6px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border: solid 1px #ededed;
  height: 57px;
  font-family: HelveticaNeue-Thin;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: 100;
  color: #4a4a4a;
  padding-top: 1%;
}

.my-container2 {
  margin-left: 5%;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
  margin-right: 5%;
  margin-top: 0%;
  padding: 5%;
  position: relative;
  height: 35%;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}

.my-container2-item {
  height: 85%;
  width: 90%;
  border-radius: 30px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: solid 1px #979797;
  z-index: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 5%;
  top: 7.5%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.my-container2-item-content {
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 10%;
  font-family: HelveticaNeue-Thin;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: 100;
  text-align: center;
  color: #4a4a4a;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: [
    'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080',
    'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
    './index.jsx'
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.jsx?$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loader: 'react-hot!babel'
    }]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/dist',
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './',
    hot: true
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
  ]
};
```

I am using semantic ui as base and then topping up with classes as I need. In both cases, the necessary dependencies have been included via `<link />` and `<script />` tags in the template. (In future, I would be using webpack to modularize dependencies, but for now, I am embedding them in the index.html)

Also, I have narrowed the problem. It appears that my specifying the top distance and height of the div container in percentages is the problem. I can't understand why it should work one way but not the other way.

Changing the units to em/px/pt does solve the problem, and I would do that.

I would still like to understand why this is happening in the first place. Maybe because I can't articulate the problem succinctly, I did not find any relevant answers.

Comment: Do you think this could be related to jade-loader? I would recommend using an HTML template to verify this. If so then we can focus on submitting an issue to to jade-loader. Also if using uglify css prefixes can be managed in Webpack 1. Best to look into this also.

Comment: I am using plain HTML with script tags when serving through webpack. Haven't used jade-loader yet. I have actually forward engineered to webpack from HTML template. It works there even now.

Comment: Maybe related to [this issue](https://github.com/ben-eb/cssnano/issues/229) in cssnano (used by css-loader in webpack)?

Comment: Thank for the link Manolo, but though I have config-ed css loader, I have not yet imported or required any css files in my index.jsx.